# Adding href link to image attachment while sending email through python smtplib

Tags: python, email, attachment, mime, smtplib

I'm sending images as attachments using smtplib, and attaching them as `email.mime.base.MIMEBase` objects. These images show up inline with the email body. I want these images to be clickable. Is it possible to add hrefs to each of these images?

Here's the code for attaching the image:

```
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = email_username
msg['To'] = ", ".join(destination_list)
msg['Subject'] = "Subject goes here"

message_body = "<b>Message body</b>"

msg.attach(MIMEText(message_body, 'html'))

part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
part.set_payload(open('attachment.png','rb').read())
encoders.encode_base64(part)
part.add_header('Content-Disposition')
msg.attach(part)
```

Comment: If I'm interpreting you correctly; you'd give them `cid`s when creating them, and refer to these identifiers in your html

Comment: I don't follow. This is what I'm doing:
            `part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')`
            `part.set_payload((attachment).read())`
            `encoders.encode_base64(part)`
            `part.add_header('Content-Disposition')`

Comment: I'd suggest updating your question with more details…  that said, have a look in the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html